# usb plugin/out in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've written a program in Linux bash using udev and bash scripting.

when a usb is attached, udev rule executes which calls a script. that script read /var/log/messages file and get info about attached usb hard drive from log file and send info in email.

Program is working fine but I've encountered a problem. when I try to remove usb, I have to shake it (as it is firmly injected inside), so what happens is that in removal process, it removes, attaches, removes attach and then finally remove. due to this my email format gets disturb and i dont get proper information.also it generates multiple useless emails and i get following logs:

```
May 04 13:06:13 coil sendEmail[12467]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:13 coil vmbackup[12450]: USB Removed: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
May  4 13:06:16 coil kernel: [8474935.215393] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, address 126
May  4 13:06:16 coil kernel: [8474935.601292] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 127
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474935.868637] usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474935.915429] scsi85 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474935.982734] input: Western Digital My Book as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.1/input/input82
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474935.982808] generic-usb 0003:1058:1102.0050: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Western Digital My Book] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-6/input1
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474935.982808] generic-usb 0003:1058:1102.0050: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Western Digital My Book] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-6/input1
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474936.084957] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, address 127
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474936.500051] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474936.769487] usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
May  4 13:06:17 coil kernel: [8474936.815499] scsi86 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
May  4 13:06:18 coil kernel: [8474936.882954] input: Western Digital My Book as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.1/input/input83
May  4 13:06:18 coil kernel: [8474936.883044] generic-usb 0003:1058:1102.0051: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Western Digital My Book] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-6/input1
May  4 13:06:22 coil kernel: [8474941.837814] scsi 86:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book          1028 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
May  4 13:06:22 coil kernel: [8474941.838208] sd 86:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
May  4 13:06:22 coil kernel: [8474941.838208] sd 86:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
May  4 13:06:23 coil kernel: [8474941.860051] sd 86:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
May  4 13:06:23 coil kernel: [8474941.873798] sd 86:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
May  4 13:06:23 coil kernel: [8474941.955971]  sdc: sdc1
May  4 13:06:23 coil kernel: [8474942.014853] sd 86:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
May 04 13:06:23 coil sendEmail[12495]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:23 coil vmbackup[12478]: USB Added: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
May 04 13:06:26 coil sendEmail[12527]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:26 coil vmbackup[12510]: USB Removed: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
May 04 13:06:35 coil sendEmail[12546]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:35 coil vmbackup[12535]: USB Added: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
May 04 13:06:37 coil sendEmail[12576]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:37 coil vmbackup[12559]: USB Removed: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
May 04 13:06:48 coil sendEmail[12596]: Email was sent successfully!
May 4 13:06:48 coil vmbackup[12585]: USB Added: Email sent to backupjobs@domain.com
```

Now I know that this is not coding problem. But I want to know if somehow i can fix this issue? and care this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some sort of de-bouncing in your script.  Whenever it's called check if it's been called recently (< 1 or 2 seconds), and if so, don't do anything.  You can use a file as a timestamp in /tmp as your time marker.

Something like this might work:

```
delta=2  # 2 seconds of debounce
stampfile=/tmp/stamp
now=$(date +%s)
then=$(< $stampfile)
[[ -z $then ]] && then=$now
diff=$((now-then))
if [[ $((diff < delta)) ]]; then
   exit
else
   echo $now > $stampfile
fi
```